# Parsing a XML file derived from the internet

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse a xml file that i extracted from the internet:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="https://my325415.crm.ondemand.com/sap/byd/odata/v1/c4c.svc/">
<id>
https://xxxxx.xxxx.com/sap/byd/odata/v1/c4c.svc/https://xxxxxx.xxxx.com/sap/byd/odata/v1/c4c.svc/OpportunityCollection/?$format=xml
</id>
<title type="text">OpportunityCollection</title>
<updated>2018-09-19T19:58:11Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link href="OpportunityCollection" rel="self" title="OpportunityCollection"/>
<entry>
<id>
https://myxxxx.xxxx.ondemand.com/sap/byd/odata/v1/c4c.svc/OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxx')
</id>
<title type="text">Test Syracuse Zoo - Opp</title>
<updated>2018-09-19T19:58:11Z</updated>
<category term="xxxxxx" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<link href="OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxxx')" rel="edit" title="Opportunity"/>
<link href="OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxx')/OpportunityProduct" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/OpportunityProduct" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="OpportunityProduct"/>
<link href="OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxxx')/OpportunitySalesTeam" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/OpportunitySalesTeam" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="OpportunitySalesTeam"/>
<link href="OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxx')/OpportunityInvolvedParty" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/OpportunityInvolvedParty" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="OpportunityInvolvedParty"/>
<link href="OpportunityCollection('xxxxxxxxxxx')/Task" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Task" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Task"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:ObjectID>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</d:ObjectID>
<d:ExpectedRevenueAmount m:type="c4c.Amount">
<d:currencyCode>USD</d:currencyCode>
<d:content>0.00</d:content>
</d:ExpectedRevenueAmount>
<d:ProbabilityPercent>25</d:ProbabilityPercent>
<d:Name>Test Syracuse Zoo - Opp</d:Name>
<d:AccountName>DO NOT USE 3 - DOMESTIC</d:AccountName>
<d:StartDate>2016-11-21T00:00:00</d:StartDate>
<d:CloseDate>2017-02-27T00:00:00</d:CloseDate>
<d:SalesCycle>Z1</d:SalesCycle>
<d:SalesCycleText>JMA - General Opportunity</d:SalesCycleText>
<d:SalesPhase>Z2</d:SalesPhase>
<d:SalesPhaseText>Budgetary Quote - 25%</d:SalesPhaseText>
<d:ReasonForStatus>Z24</d:ReasonForStatus>
<d:ReasonForStatusText>Active Opportunity</d:ReasonForStatusText>
<d:Source>Z9</d:Source>
<d:SourceText>Sales Referral - from Anixter</d:SourceText>
<d:PrimaryContact>Test First Name Test Last Name</d:PrimaryContact>
<d:ID>21</d:ID>
<d:ChangedOn>2017-03-31T02:10:29.3910740Z</d:ChangedOn>
<d:Status>2</d:Status>
<d:StatusText>In Process</d:StatusText>
<d:AccountID>100002150</d:AccountID>
<d:OwnerID>8000000011</d:OwnerID>
<d:CRMUILink>
https://xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.com/sap/public/byd/runtime?bo=COD_OPPORTUNITY_THINGTYPE&nav_mode=TI&param.Key=00163E0813301ED6AC8355A5C1DA8831
</d:CRMUILink>
<d:ExternalID>00000000000000000000000000000000001</d:ExternalID>
<d:Owner>Sandy Blau</d:Owner>
<d:DaysUntilClosing>-569</d:DaysUntilClosing>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<link rel="next" href="https://my325415.crm.ondemand.com/sap/byd/odata/v1/c4c.svc/OpportunityCollection/?$format=xml&$skiptoken=101%20"/>
</feed>
```

Here is the code i am using to parse it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlp = ET.XMLParser(encoding = "utf-8")


xmldoc=ET.parse('foot.xml',parser=xmlp)
root = xmldoc.getroot()
print(root)
```

The issue with this code is that it only reads the feed tag and gives the following output:

```
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed' at 0x0000000002D7B0E8>
```

I want to get the data between all the children nodes without hardcoding the element names. I am only concerned about **the elements in the entry tag**.

Since this file is extracted from the internet, i have no way of changing how the input data is flowing in.

Please help, this is my first time trying out xml parsing and i have looked at a lot of sources.

Comment: It seems you correctly parsed the file. The return value you get is the root element from the xml, meaning everything is working fine. What is your problem again?

Comment: @nosklo Sorry, i have updated the question. I actually want to extract all the child node values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the string representation of the Element object returned by the builtin **repr** method, not the content of the root tree.

To see the tags in the object try:

```
for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for more info on accessing specific tags.

Comment: Hi, is there an easy way to just access the child nodes of another child nodes? Say the nodes under the node 'entry'.